# Interior of simple closed curve

Tags: graphics, regions

If we are given a closed curve $(x(t),y(t))$, $0<t<L$, then how to extract the region inside it ?

I have seen answers that use `FilledCurve` and `BSpline`, but I don't want to extract some points and then join them again into an spline. For instance, consider the rhombus

```
 x[t_] := -(Piecewise[{{-1, Inequality[0, Less, t, LessEqual, 2]}, 
   {-3 + t, Inequality[2, Less, t, LessEqual, 4]}, 
   {1, Inequality[4, Less, t, LessEqual, 6]}, 
   {7 - t, Inequality[6, Less, t, LessEqual, 8]}}, 0]/Sqrt[2]) + 
   Piecewise[{{-1 + t, Inequality[0, Less, t, LessEqual, 2]}, 
  {1, Inequality[2, Less, t, LessEqual, 4]}, 
  {5 - t, Inequality[4, Less, t, LessEqual, 6]}, 
  {-1, Inequality[6, Less, t, LessEqual, 8]}}, 0]/Sqrt[2]


 y[t_] := Piecewise[{{-1, Inequality[0, Less, t, LessEqual, 2]}, 
  {-3 + t, Inequality[2, Less, t, LessEqual, 4]}, 
  {1, Inequality[4, Less, t, LessEqual, 6]}, 
  {7 - t, Inequality[6, Less, t, LessEqual, 8]}}, 0]/Sqrt[2] + 
  Piecewise[{{-1 + t, Inequality[0, Less, t, LessEqual, 2]}, 
  {1, Inequality[2, Less, t, LessEqual, 4]}, 
  {5 - t, Inequality[4, Less, t, LessEqual, 6]}, 
  {-1, Inequality[6, Less, t, LessEqual, 8]}}, 0]/Sqrt[2]
```

(nothing special about it, just as an example) then how to get interior as a discretized region ?

Comment: `poly = Polygon@Table[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 1, 8, 1}]` ?

Comment: @Syed True. But as I mentioned, it doesn't make too much sense to discretize a continuous closed curve whose analytic expression is known.

Comment: If you don't want any discretization, then I think you're going to need to use the implicit region functionality. We could "regionize" your example with `ParametricRegion[{x[t], y[t]}, {{t, 0, 8}}]`, but that just gets us a 1-D region. To get a 2-D region, I think you're going to need to provide the 2-D parameterization. You could do this by adding a second parameter and filling out the interior with vectors from {0,0} to {x[t],y[t]}. I'm not aware of a built-in function that automatically creates "interior" regions from non-mesh boundary regions in the general case.

Comment: To go the discretization route, you don't need splines. Your function can generate a parametric plot on which you can use DiscretizeGraphics. You can control the refinement of the discretiztion. Then you'll have a boundary made up of 1-D sub-regions. Extract these and create a FilledCurve and discretize the results. That seems like more steps than necessary, so maybe someone else has a more direct route. But the main point is that I don't think there is a built in function that creates interior regions bounded by parameterized functions defining the boundary.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I overlooked your last comment...so you DO want a discretized region. I'll put together an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Since in the original parametric equation,`{x[0],y[0]}` is not equal to `{x[8],y[8]}`, it means that such curve is not a closed curve. We need to  replace some `Less` to `LessEqual`.

```
Clear[x,y];
x[t_] = -(Piecewise[{{-1, 
         Inequality[0, LessEqual, t, LessEqual, 2]}, {-3 + t, 
         Inequality[2, Less, t, LessEqual, 4]}, {1, 
         Inequality[4, Less, t, LessEqual, 6]}, {7 - t, 
         Inequality[6, Less, t, LessEqual, 8]}}, 0]/Sqrt[2]) + 
   Piecewise[{{-1 + t, Inequality[0, LessEqual, t, LessEqual, 2]}, {1,
        Inequality[2, Less, t, LessEqual, 4]}, {5 - t, 
       Inequality[4, Less, t, LessEqual, 6]}, {-1, 
       Inequality[6, Less, t, LessEqual, 8]}}, 0]/Sqrt[2];

y[t_] = Piecewise[{{-1, 
       Inequality[0, LessEqual, t, LessEqual, 2]}, {-3 + t, 
       Inequality[2, Less, t, LessEqual, 4]}, {1, 
       Inequality[4, Less, t, LessEqual, 6]}, {7 - t, 
       Inequality[6, Less, t, LessEqual, 8]}}, 0]/Sqrt[2] + 
   Piecewise[{{-1 + t, Inequality[0, LessEqual, t, LessEqual, 2]}, {1,
        Inequality[2, Less, t, LessEqual, 4]}, {5 - t, 
       Inequality[4, Less, t, LessEqual, 6]}, {-1, 
       Inequality[6, Less, t, LessEqual, 8]}}, 0]/Sqrt[2];
```

```
{x[0], y[0]} == {x[8], y[8]}
```

> `True`.

- Now we can directly use `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` by add `Exclusions -> None` to contain the boundary point of segment to make the curves be a closed curve.

```
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 8}, 
  Exclusions -> None] // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful ! Thank you.

Comment: Nice! I hoped there would be a better way!

Answer (score 3):

This seems a bit cumbersome, I know, but I don't know of a direct route.

```
boundary = ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 8}];
DiscretizeGraphics[FilledCurve[MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeGraphics[boundary], 1]]]
```